# How to deduct 1 min from iso time

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

I used this below code to get iso time using java. i want 1min old time in order to get 1min older data from my DB.
In my DB time is saved as ios format. Can anybody tell me how can i deduct 1 min from current time using iso time format ?

//my code

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'");
        df.setTimeZone(tz);
        String nowAsISO = df.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using `Calendar` class:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeZone(tz);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) - 1);

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'");
String nowAsISO = df.format(c.getTime());

System.out.println(nowAsISO);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: Please vote up, if that helped. Cheers.

Comment: definitely I'll. 
it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
    LocalDateTime ldt = Instant.now()
                    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                    .toLocalDateTime()
                    .minusMinutes(1);
```

Comment: Remark: That will work only in JDK 8.

Comment: Yes! Its been a while since Java 7 was EOLed

Comment: thanks. the above one worked.